# moving from GoogleMobileAds.framework to xcframework error

Tags: ios, admob

I changed my framework references from MobileAds.framework to xcframework following the instructions(manual) at https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start.

But for some reason I get the error as shown below. I cleared the cache. Even tried adding a new simulator. It still says the same. Can someone please help?
I am on Mac OS Catalina and Xcode 12.4. Cannot upgrade my OS or Xcode anymore.I am also unable to run the app on any of my devices. This app has been running fine, it was time to do minor UI color changes so nothing else has changed in the code.

*Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/User1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8AF69E5B-FD16-4C80-B9F5-DE4A4A0B78BA/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.8rg85u/extracted/Myapp.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework; Extra info about Info.plist: Couldn't stat /Users/User1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8AF69E5B-FD16-4C80-B9F5-DE4A4A0B78BA/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.8rg85u/extracted/Myapp.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory*

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution. Target->Frameworks->All Google admob related frameworks had "Embed and sign" selected, made them "Do not embed" and the app is running.